# Using seek to listen get only uncommitted offset from beginning

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I am using Spring Kafka and have a requirement where I have to listen from a DLQ topic and put the message to another topic after few minutes. Here I am only acknowledging a msg only when it is put to another topic else I am not committing it and calling kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.stop() which is stopping my kafka consumer. Then there is scheduled cron job running after every 3 minutes and starts the consumer by running kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.start() and since auto.offset.reset is set to earliest then consumer is getting all msgs from previously uncommitted offset and checking their eligibility to be put on other topic.

This approach is working fine for small volume but for very large volume I am not seeing the expected retries in both topics. So I am suspecting that this might be happening because I am using kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.stop() to stop the consumer. If I am able to seek to beginning of offset for each partition and get all msgs from uncommitted offset then I don't have to stop and start my consumer.

For this, I tried ConsumerSeekAware.onPartitionAssigned and calling callback.seekToBeginning() to reset offsets. But looks like it's also consuming all committed offset which is increasing huge load on my services. So is there anything I am missing or seekToBeginning always read all msgs(committed and uncommitted).

and is there any way to trigger partition assignment manually while running kafka consumer so that it goes to onPartitionAssigned method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `auto.offset.reset` is set to earliest then consumer is getting all msgs from previously uncommitted

`auto.offset.reset` is meaningless if there is a committed offset; it just determines the behavior if there is no committed offset.

> seekToBeginning always read all msgs(committed and uncommitted).

Kafka maintains 2 pointers - the current position and the committed offset; seek has nothing to do with committed offset, `seekToBeginning` just changes the position to the earliest record, so the next poll will return all records.

> This approach is working fine for small volume but for very large volume I am not seeing the expected retries in both topics. So I am suspecting that this might be happening because I am using `kafkaListenerEndpointRegistry.stop()` to stop the consumer.

That should not be a problem; you might want to consider using a container stopping error handler instead; then throw an exception and the container will stop itself (you should also set the `stopImmediate` container property).

https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#container-stopping-error-handlers

Comment: Docs for the error handler: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/current/reference/html/#container-stopping-error-handlers